# Does (and if so how) Quentin Meillassoux prove that everything is contingent?

Tags: metaphysics

When Quentin Meillassoux says that "contingency is a necessity", "contingency is absolute", etc. what is trying to imply is that everything is contingent. But (where) has he proven that? It is true that "anything can happen" is a common adage. But as a person who is coming from a physics background I can say that science is not very comfortable with the Meillassoux's idea of contingency. We know that in science, certain things can be predicted with amazing accuracy. I know that Meillassoux would say that past experiences do not guarantee that things would repeat in the future. But as far as I am concerned, to make a bold claim that contingency is a necessity, one must be able to provide a solid proof and mere gut feeling (probably based on life experiences, etc.) is not enough. Therefore I am grateful if someone could kindly explain on what basis that Meillassaoux says that everything is contingent.

Another related question: Isn't contingency contingent?

Comment: Small typo in the very first sentence of the question: the word he is missing. Instead of ".... etc. what is trying to imply is ....", it should be "... etc. what he is trying to imply is ...."

Comment: To clarify, "everything is contingent" is very different from "anything can happen". According to Meillassoux, the laws of nature are contingent, as in they could have been otherwise, but they are, nonetheless, binding in our actual world, hence "anything" can not happen. That things can be predicted has no bearing on whether they are contingent or not.

Comment: The question as posed in the title is interesting, but as Conifold says the body text of your post is running together several different philosophical issues. Maybe simplify it?

Comment: I would also suggest some clarification,.The idea that every 'thing' is contingent is widely endorsed, but it would not follow that 'anything can happen'. I wonder if you're giving the wrong meaning to 'contingent'. .  .

Comment: A simplification (as transitionsynthesis has suggested) and a clarification:

I have to admit that what Conifold and PeterJ say are correct. I had got contingency and “anything can happen” mixed up.

Therefore let me re-write my question (However I have to say that my understanding of Meillassoux’s formulations can still be imperfect.)

As transitionsynthesis has indicated I have split this into two parts

Comment: (1) As far as I understand, in order to be able to go beyond the 'finitude', it must be possible for anything to happen. (The name of his book is After Finitude) Otherwise, we are still within the 'finitude'; aren’t we? (eg:- According to Meillassoux, things are not required to remain static and any existing thing can change - even something that is seemingly eternal can change. Even a god can appear in future). 

I think in this regard, it is import to reproduce a few sentences from Meillassoux’s lecture titled “Time without Becoming” and delivered at Middlesex University in 2008.

Comment: “Hyper-chaos is very different from what we call usually ‘chaos’. By chaos we usually mean is order, randomness, the eternal becoming of everything. But these properties are not properties of Hyper-Chaos: its contingency is so radical that even becoming, disorder, or randomness can be destroyed by it, and replaced by order, determinism, and fixity. Things are so contingent in Hyper-chaos that time is able to destroy even the becoming of things.”

Comment: I fully agree with the Conifold’s statement that laws of nature could have been otherwise. Since there is no ultimate root cause (as Meillassoux thinks – this is my understanding) we cannot argue that things have to be the way they are.

It is true that the laws of nature are binding. But I don’t think that Meillassoux thinks that laws of nature are expected to stay as they are forever.

Comment: It is true that speed of light, charge of electron, etc. could have been different. As far as what Meillassoux is saying we cannot think of a reason that prevents physical constants having entirely different values. But my concern is as far as my understanding of Meillassoux’s line of thought is concerned, it is not only that physical constants could have been different, they could also be different in future – even tomorrow.

Comment: As far as I understand, Meillassoux does not think that there is something in this world which is keeping the values of physical constants constant. That is why I believe that science is not very comfortable with the Meillassoux’s thinking. (I am not saying that science believes that “there is something in this world which is keeping the values of physical constants constant”. Science believes that if someone wants to argue that values of physical constants could change in future then that person should provide sufficient reasons for it. He cannot just say it.)

Comment: (2) Speaking about proving contingency (i.e. my main query), Meillassoux says everything is contingent because Hume said it would not be possible to identify a root cause (or ultimate cause) for anything. Am I wrong? Another question I want to ask is even if each and everything is contingent, does it imply contingency? (or is it enough for contingency to exist?) In other words, should there be a contingency for each and everything to be contingent? Is contingency the root cause that is responsible for making each and everything contingent?

Comment: If so, is Meillassoux admitting that there is a root cause and that root cause is contingency. But if contingency is also contingent then what happens?